# Python: Custom print function that prints function text

Tags: python, printing, custom-function, f-string

Python script:

```
text = "abcde"
print("text[::-1] : ", text[::-1])
print("text[5:0:-1] : ", text[5:0:-1])
```

Output:

```
text[::-1] :  edcba
text[5:0:-1] :  edcb
```

Can a custom function be defined that avoids duplicity in typing?
For ex:

```
text = "abcde"
def fuc(x):
    print(x, ":", x)
    
fuc(text[::-1])
fuc(text[5:0:-1])
```

Reqd. Output:

```
text[::-1] :  edcba
text[5:0:-1] :  edcb
```

Comment: It's called a slice object. It already exists natively in python.

Comment: My question is not related to silce object. I want to define a custom function that would save me the trouble of having to type "b[::-1]" twice in print("b[::-1] : ", b[::-1]).

Comment: @Sayse - I got an error 
"File "<fstring>", line 1
    (b[::1]=)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you *could* use eval, something like `def debug_print(expression): print(expression, ':', eval(expression))`. and then you would call it with the string, e.g. `debug_print('a[::-1]')`. This wouldn't be terrible if it is for debugging purposes and not for production code, but it definitely presents a security risk if `expression` is from an untrusted input

Answer (score 2):

In python 3.8+, you can use a [self documenting expression](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging)

```
>>> print(f"{a[::-1]=}") 
a[::-1]='edcba'
```

Comment: I'm getting a SyntaxError pointing to the equal to: 
File "<fstring>", line 1
    (b[::1]=)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @RahulAhuja - Then it doesn't look like you're using python 3.8

Comment: I have Python 3.7.4 and am using Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

A solution involving string interpolation is possible using f-strings.  However, f-strings are only available with Python 3.8+

However, we can easily implement string interpolation as described by [How to Implement String Interpolation in Python](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-implement-string-interpolation-in-python-br)

Current Modification extends the above reference to allow expressions in addition to variable lookups.

```
import sys
from re import sub

def interp(s):
  '''Implement simple string interpolation to handle
    "{var}" replaces var with its value from locals
    "{var=}" replaces var= with var=value, where value is the value of var from locals
    "{expressions} use eval to evaluate expressions (make eval safe by only allowing items from local functions and variables in expression'''

  # 1. Implement self-documenting expressions similar to https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging
  s1 = sub( r'{\s*(.*?)=\s*}', lambda m: m.group(1) + '=' + '{' + m.group(1) + '}', s)

  # Get the locals from the previous frame
  previous_frame = sys._getframe(1)  # i.e. current frame(0), previous is frame(1)
  d = previous_frame.f_locals        # get locals from previous frame

  # 2--Replace variable and expression with values
  # Use technique from http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html to limit eval to make it safe
  # by only allowing locals from d and no globals
  s2 = sub(r'{\s*([^\s]+)\s*}', lambda m: str(d[m.group(1)]) if m.group(1) in d else str(eval(m.group(1), {}, d)), s1)
  return s2

# Test
a = "abcde"

print(interp("a has value {a}"))  # without self-doc =
#Output>>> a has value abcde

print(interp("{a[::-1]=}"))       # with self-doc =
#Output>>> a[::-1]=edcba

print(interp('{a[4:0:-1]=}'))     # with self-doc =
#Output>>> a[4:0:-1]=edcb

print(interp('sum {1+1}') # without self-doc =
#Output>>> sum 2

print(interp('{1+1=}'))  # with self-doc =
#Output>>> 1+1=2
```